# digital signature with specific itext version 4.2.0

Tags: ssl, itext, pdfbox, x509

If you reply, I appreciate if you can write in such a way that a newbie to this field can understand.

A few questions:

1)

Does anyone know if itext version (specifically) 4.2.0 is able to add digital signature with a certificate from a Certificate Authority?

https://github.com/ymasory/iText-4.2.0

The reason I may be interested in version 4.2.0 is because it's MPL/LGPL.

2) What is X.509?  From my reading

"In the X.509 system, a certification authority issues a certificate binding a public key to a particular distinguished name in the X.500 tradition, or to an alternative name such as an e-mail address or a DNS entry.[citation needed]"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509

Am I correct that if I buy a Certificate from a Certified Authority, I'll be issued a x.509 certificate?  So what X.509 means is that it's simply a certificate issued by a CA and is not a certificate I made up myself?

3) If this is the case, will I be able to use X.509 with itext version 4.2.0?

4) What about X.509 with pdfbox?

Appearantly, pdfbox has a command line that will accept X.509:

https://pdfbox.apache.org/commandline/

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Concerning 4.2.0: if you want to be sure, you are talking about the actual iText 4.2.0, you should check out the matching tag from the iText svn repository, not some third-party repository.

Comment: There has never been an official 4.2.0 release issued by the creators of iText. The last version available under the MPL/LGPL dates from 2009 and you shouldn't use that either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696851/can-itext-2-1-7-or-earlier-can-be-used-commercially/25698526#25698526

Comment: For signing with that version look here: http://cysorz-software-hardware.blogspot.de/2008/11/how-to-sign-pdf-using-itext-and.html

Answer (score 0):

> 1) Does anyone know if itext version (specifically) 4.2.0 is able to add digital signature with a certificate from a Certificate Authority?

iText can be used for creating integrated PDF signatures. A certificate obviously does *not* suffice (the certificate is public after all), the signing process requires the accompanying private key. If you are the holder of a certificate from some CA, though, you will generally have access to that private key, too.

iText versions before some 5.X version (I don't know which exactly, though) only supported old integrated PDF signature profiles which partially already were deprecated (*not recommended for interoperable signatures*) in the current standard ISO 32000-1 from 2008. If you use iText 4.2.0 correctly, you can create proper basic integrated PDF signatures. If you are interested in non-basic stuff (field locking, non-basic PDF Advanced Electronic Signatures, document time stamps, Long Term Validation support, ...), though, you'll have to re-program much already present in the current iText versions.

> https://github.com/ymasory/iText-4.2.0

As mentioned in a comment before,  if you want to be sure you are talking about the actual iText 4.2.0, you should check out the matching tag from the iText svn repository, not some third-party repository.

> The reason I may be interested in version 4.2.0 is because it's MPL/LGPL.

As Bruno mentioned in a comment before, 4.2.0 was never meant as an actual release; it merely was a tag on the last iText source code state before the great re-factoring resulting in 5.0.0. Furthermore it is ancient (from the last decade) and it has been announced that its code may present legal issues.

> 2) What is X.509? ...
>   Am I correct that if I buy a Certificate from a Certified Authority, I'll be issued a x.509 certificate? So what X.509 means is that it's simply a certificate issued by a CA and is not a certificate I made up myself?

To quote the article you linked to,

> > X.509 specifies, amongst other things, standard formats for public key certificates, certificate revocation lists, attribute certificates, and a certification path validation algorithm.

When talking about X.509 certificates, one talks about public key certificates with a binary structure as specified in X.509. This format is supported in a very wide set of security related applications

Thus, a self-signed certificate (you made up yourself) should also be in X.509 format to be usable anywhere.

> 3) If this is the case, will I be able to use X.509 with itext version 4.2.0?

In limited ways, yes, see remarks on 4.2.0 above.

> 4) What about X.509 with pdfbox?

PDFBox versions 1.x have very limited signature creation and validation support. It greatly improves in the version 2.0.0 currently under development and rivals iText 4.2.0 but it is still work in progress and may improve even more.

Comment: MKL, in reference to: "...If you use iText 4.2.0 correctly, you can create proper basic integrated PDF signatures. If you are interested in non-basic stuff (..Long Term Validation support..), though, you'll have to re-program much already present in the current iText versions." Unsure which I need; all I need is to digitally sign with CA cert and prove that the pdf hasn't been modified.  Will using itext 4.2.0. be able to do this where current acrobat reader will validate pdf correctly? Are you associated w/ itext? Any historical case where new adobe reader failed to validate old itext?

Comment: *all I need is to digitally sign with CA cert* - this is fairly easy - *and prove that the pdf hasn't been modified* - how easy this is depends on how deep your prove shall be. Whether Adobe reader accepts your signature now or not mostly depends on your choice of CA. If you are not only interested in the situation now but also in a few years, you will have to look into LTV mechanisms.

Comment: "all I need is to digitally sign with CA cert - this is fairly easy - and prove that the pdf hasn't been modified - how easy this is depends on how deep your prove shall be." Well, so long as I see the blue banner is valid, and it says This certificate is trusted to: a) sign documents and b) Certify documents.  I don't need any of the execute dymanic content and privilege stuff.  Just simple A and B.  that's all i need.  Tell me which choices of CA would work accept my signature.  Also please address part about had there been cases where new adobe reader failed to validate old itext? thx.